# DataflowPipeline and DataflowPipelineOptions vs. Pipeline and PipelineOptions

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

After some reasearch, I found that the Google cloud API says you should use `Pipeline.create(PipelineOptions)` rather than `DataflowPipeline.create(DataflowPipelineOptions)`, but it doesn't explain why. Could anyone clarify this for me?

Also, a follow-up question, using `Pipeline.create(DataflowPipelineOptions)` also works when running a pipeline, is there any good reason not to rather than reimplementing `PipelineOptions` with attributes `DataflowPipelineOptions` already has, such as project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PipelineOptions` is a special class designed to hold a collection of options of many kinds at the same time. `DataflowPipelineOptions` is only one of the subsets of options it can hold, but when referring to the full collections of options, it makes more sense to refer to it as `PipelineOptions` because it is a more general and abstract concept, even though it is the same object as the `DataflowPipelineOptions`.

`PipelineOptions` is not even Dataflow-specific; partially because pipelines can be run using runners other than Dataflow, such as Spark and Flink, which have their own options. Hopefully this answers your second question.

Please see [Specifying execution parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params) for details.